# Scala: Prepending an Underscore to Function Name

Tags: scala

I have encountered an example where we have a function that takes a param and also defines some inner functions.Then we execute one of the functions based on what the value of this param is. All the inner function have an underscore prepended to the name. **Is there some semantic significance to this "underscore style"?**

```
def outsideFunction(param: SomeType) {
  _inner1() = { ...}
  _inner2() = {....}

  param match {
   case result: Int => _inner1()
   case result: String => _inner2()
 }
}
```

Comment: http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions
"Underscores in names (_) are not actually forbidden by the compiler, but are strongly discouraged as they have special meaning within the Scala syntax" also ctrl-f for "Hungarian notation", it may be what your code is using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there some semantic significance to this "underscore style"?

No. I'd suspect someone who is used to a (far from universal, but not uncommon) Java convention of prefixing *fields* with `_` to more easily distinguish them from local variables. As cdncat's comment says, this is a specific case of Hungarian notation.

At any rate, if the functions are really each used only once, I can't really think of any reason to prefer it over

```
def outsideFunction(param: SomeType) =
  param match {
    case result: Int => // body of _inner1
    case result: String => // body of _inner2
  }
```